# Add level classes to nested list with Javascript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

Im trying to add level clases to a list with nested list items.
I want the following structure.

```html
<ul class="parent parent-level-1">
  <li class="child child-level-1"><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li class="child child-level-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="parent parent-level-2">
      <li class="child child-level-2"><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul class="parent parent-level-3">
          <li class="child child-level-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child child-level-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="child child-level-2"><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul class="parent parent-level-3">
          <li class="child child-level-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child child-level-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child child-level-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="child child-level-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="parent parent-level-2">
      <li class="child child-level-2"><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="child child-level-1"><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li class="child child-level-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="parent parent-level-2">
      <li class="child child-level-2"><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see there are some nested list inside the parent list that at the same time may content another nested lists.
I tried the following Javascript functio where **parent** is the parent of the main list and **level** an integer for the first level, could be 0 or 1.

```js
function addLevelClass(parent, level) {
  const iteration = parent.querySelectorAll("ul");

  const firstUL = parent.querySelector("ul");
  firstUL.classList.add("parent", "parent-level-" + level);

  const firstItems = parent.querySelectorAll("li");

  console.info(firstItems);

  // No point if no list items.
  if (!firstItems.length) {
    return;
  }

  //loop trough fisrt-level li
  for (let c = 0; c < firstItems.length; c++) {
    const childrenLi = firstItems[c];

    //add a child class to the li
    childrenLi.classList.add("child", "child-level-" + level);
  }

  // No point if no list items.
  if (!iteration.length) {
    return;
  }
  for (let g = 0; g < iteration.length; g++) {
    const levelIncrement = level + g;

    const parentUL = iteration[g].querySelector("ul");

    //add a parent class to the ul
    parentUL.classList.add(
      "parent",
      "parent-level-" + (level + levelIncrement)
    );

    //fetch all the li's that are direct children of the ul
    const childItems = parentUL.querySelectorAll("li");

    // No point if no list items.
    if (!childItems.length) {
      return;
    }

    //loop trough each li
    for (let c = 0; c < childItems.length; c++) {
      const childrenLi = childItems[c];

      //add a child class to the li
      childrenLi.classList.add(
        "child",
        "child-level-" + (level + levelIncrement)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The function gets lost somewhere in the 3er level and fails setting levels for the rest of the list.

Comment: You're trying to do a DFS btw -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand this problem is that the HTML structure is a Tree data structure (actually it's a DAG, if you wish to research further).

These problems are part of data structures CS101 (and how to traverse/search). The solution provided is DFS.

However, to approach this problem you need to consider `recursion`.

i.e. given a tree structure of the following

```
| root
|
|- leaf node
|- node with children
 |- leaf node
```

So the idea is where you find the root node first.
Here you are looking for `document.querySelector('ul')`

then you're going to look for leaf nodes within the `root ul`.
here you'll do something like `document.querySelector('ul > li')`. this give you the existing child nodes from the root.

from there - you'll need to switch the parent with the child to perform the action recursively.

i'll provide an example below:

```js
// helper fn
const findChildren = el => [...el.children].filter(el => el.tagName === "LI")

const root = document.querySelector("ul");
const children = findChildren(root);


const traverse = (baseNode, children, iter = 1) => {
  // process baseNode here with iter here
  baseNode.classList.add(`list-${iter.toString()}`)

  for (child of children) {
     child.classList.add(`child-${iter.toString()}`)
     let hasGranChild = [...child.children].filter(el => el.tagName === "UL").length

     if (hasGranChild) {
       let newChild = [...child.children].find(el => el.tagName === "UL");
       const granChildren = findChildren(newChild)

       traverse(newChild, granChildren, iter + 1)
     }
  }
}

traverse(root, children)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Result**

```html
<ul class="list-1">
  <li class="child-1"><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li class="child-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="list-2">
      <li class="child-2"><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul class="list-3">
          <li class="child-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="child-2"><a>Title level 2</a>
        <ul class="list-3">
          <li class="child-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
          <li class="child-3"><a>Title level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="child-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="list-2">
      <li class="child-2"><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="child-1"><a>Title level 1</a></li>
  <li class="child-1"><a>Title level 1</a>
    <ul class="list-2">
      <li class="child-2"><a>Title level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

within the recursive nature of the function, you can pass in the current "level" within the function arguments. 
By setting the starting `iter = 1` you don't care how "deep" the tree goes.
And as you use CSS selectors direct child (i.e. `el1 > el2`) you're asking, can you give me the direct children of `el1 which are el2`?

Comment: const children = parent.querySelectorAll('ul > li'); takes all the li items of the tree.

Comment: Can't do this work. Please, could you explain how helper function works?

Comment: i'll add it as a jsfiddle for you convenience

Comment: @BorjaSobas this solves your issue - please upvote and accept when you're happy thanks.